# Android Quiz Timer

Tags: java, android

Good day everyone! I was making android quiz application with a timer. Every question has set 30 seconds to answer. then refresh the timer when I get to the next question. Now, I found an error in my application which my quiz timer did not refresh or back to zero even if I get to the next question? Can anyone help me? Massive thank you

public class QuizHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView timer;
private TextView countLabel;
private TextView questionLabel;
private Button answerBtn1;
private Button answerBtn2;
private Button answerBtn3;

private String rightAnswer;
private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
private int quizCount = 1;

static final private int QUIZ_COUNT = 10;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

String quizData [][] = {
//Question  
{"What is the meaning of ALCU?",
//Answer   
"The association of Local College and University",
//Choice A      
"The association of Local College and University",
//Choice B     
 "The Association of Land Colleges  and Universities",
//Choice C      
"The Association of Level Colleges and Universities"}
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_history);


    countLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countlabel);
    questionLabel= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionlabel);
    answerBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbtn1);
    answerBtn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbtn2);
    answerBtn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerbtn3);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timers);

    //Create quizArray from quizdata
    for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {

        //Prepare array
        ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]);
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]);

        //Add tmpArray to quizArray
        quizArray.add(tmpArray);

    }
    CountDownTimer countDown;
    countDown= new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
    showNextQuiz();
        }
    };
    countDown.start();
}

public  void showNextQuiz () {

    //Update quizCountLabel
    countLabel.setText("Question #" + quizCount);

    //Generate random number between 0 and 14 (Quiz Array's size -1)

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

    //Pick ine quiz set
    ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

    //Set question and right answer
    //array format
    questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
    rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

    //remove "country" from quiz and shuffle choice
    quiz.remove(0);
    Collections.shuffle(quiz);

    //Set Choices
    answerBtn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
    answerBtn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
    answerBtn3.setText(quiz.get(2));

    //Remove this quiz from quizArray
    quizArray.remove(randomNum);
}

public void checkAnswer (View view) {

    //Get pushed button
    Button answerBtn = (Button)findViewById(view.getId());
    String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

    String alertTitle;

    if(btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
        //Correct!
        alertTitle = "Correct!";
        rightAnswerCount++;
    }else {
        //Wrong
        alertTitle = "Wrong";
    }

    //create Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setMessage("Answer : \n \t \t" + rightAnswer);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Got It!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT) {
                //Show Result

                Intent resultintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultQuizHistoryActivity.class);
                resultintent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", rightAnswerCount);
                startActivity(resultintent);
            }else {
                quizCount++;
                showNextQuiz();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating CountDownTimer in onCreate method which is called once in Activity lifecycle. You should create it as instance of the class and try to reset it before displaying new question.